# Updating a relationship in Entity Framework generates SQL error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm getting headaches here. I've got a **one to zero-or-one** relationship between a Session and a User object, designed in Entity Framework 4 using the model first approach.

- A User **should** have a session (*one*)
- A Session **can** have a User (*zero-to-one*).

So, in runtime I pull a session from the database using

```
Session session = context.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Token.Equals(token));
```

and after that I create a user, created based on user input like this

```
user = context.Users.Create();

user.GUID = Guid.NewGuid();
user.Username = username;
user.Firstname = firstname;
user.Lastname = lastname;
user.Session = session;

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

and when I save, the SQL server throws an exception telling me that the GUID I try to **insert** in the database already exists, because yeah, it does. The problem is, that it **shouldnt** insert, it should **update** the session and fill the forein key that belongs with it.
*The foreign key resides on the User side of the relation, this is alright, right?*

**edit**
The user *should* be a new user. Updating the user is not what I'm trying to accomplish.
Also, the error is because the code tries to insert the session with  the same primary key value, instead of just updating it's foreing keys.

Here's a chronological list of what should be done:

- Session gets created
- Session gets saved
- Session gets selected from the database
- User gets created
- User <-> Session relations gets set
- User gets saved

And what I get is:

**Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Sessions'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Sessions'. The duplicate key value is *VALUE*. The statement has been terminated.**

Please help me out, I've been fiddling with this for the past 2 hours.

Comment: I have deleted my answer, since your problem has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Changed my answer to reflect changed problem description :)

Make sure you always use the same context instance when handling these kind of updates.

What seemed to be happening here was that session was retrieved in one context, but the user was saved in another instance of that context. Therefore, in the new context, the session was seen as new and hence, it was insterted (wrongfully)

Comment: See my edit, I suddenly realized my question was slightly vague. It's the relation that's causing the application to try to insert a duplicate session, instead of inserting a new user and updating the session

Comment: Ok, more clear indeed :) Your mention of that GUID threw me off :)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to couple the already existing Session with a new user and saving the lot.

Comment: It does look strange, because i would expect no insert (or update for that matter) on any session object. At least in the code you are showing, i cannot find a clue as to why any session should be created, inserted or updated...

Comment: you _are_ absolutely sure you are using the same instance of your context when retrieving your session and when inserting your user? I would assume so, but if you are not, it could explain why it sees the session as a new session...
What if you try to set user.Session = context.Sessions.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Token.Equals(token)); directly?

Comment: That was it! Somehow the context object changed in that few lines of code. I'll have to look into that. I want the context to be the same for every request on a per-request-per-user basis (i'm building a MVC4 API). Can you update your answer to reflect the problem I had? For any people coming here with something similir. Thank you so much, you saved my project (and probably me =P )

Comment: Just to tell what happened after some research (thanks to Oerkelens I knew where to look) it turned out my Context object changed a few times in other methods, fixed that. After that I also found a call that detached my session from the context, why it was there is still unclear to my, but now adding the session the way I tried in my question works. Today I learned: NEVER SCREW AROUND WITH YOUR CONTEXT